# Why say "she broke my heart" if the person died?

Tags: the-equalizer

In the movie *Equalizer*, when he is asked if he was married he says he was. Then asked if he broke her heart to which Denzel says she broke mine.

But in the second one when he meets his friend she mentions something about Denzel's wife passing.

At first, he was talking about her giving him a broken heart, so she did him dirty somehow. Then says she is dead (second one)

Does anyone know what happened with the wife?

Comment: So she died after breaking his heart. Maybe his heart was broken because she died. Are you asking *how* she died? Is that important for your understanding of the film?

Comment: He's reading ***her*** list of books, still having the wedding ring, talking about the shirts ***she*** loved and that he was wearing... and so on... Seems like he was so deeply in love that she broke his heart when passing away too early

Answer (score 6):

His wife died. He is saying that her death broke his heart. He is replying that way so he doesn't lie but doesn't give away any more information about himself than is necessary to remain polite and involved in the conversation.

Answer (score 4):

He's reading ***her*** list of books, still having the wedding ring, talking about the shirts ***she*** loved and that he was wearing... and so on... Seems like he was so deeply in love that she broke his heart when passing away too early. He misses her so much that he has never forgotten her, and he probably wants to keep the memories alive.

Robert McCall is a noble man. He wants to do the right thing. He fights injustice. He helps innocent people. He has a strong sense of morality. But he's also a cold-blooded killer<sup>1</sup> when it comes to help those who can't help themselves or fight for themselves. So, in order to not become a mentally disordered or insane person, he has to be emotionally detached. As such, he needs someone to balance his (lack of) emotions. His wife was the one who reminded him of being a human being.

> "I've done some bad things in my life, Nicolai. Things I'm not proud of. ***I promised someone that I love very much that I would never go back to being that person***. But for you, I'm gonna make an exception. You asked me what I saw when I looked at you. What do you see when you look at me?" *Robert McCall to Nicolaï* (in the restaurant)

It's never clearly said, but McCall probably *retired* himself<sup>2</sup> after his beloved wife's death<sup>3</sup>.

<sup>1. But he also gives his victims a chance to straighten things up before taking action. Very nice to nice people, very nasty to bad people. It's also a way to justify his acts, and not portrait himself as a monster.</sup>

<sup>2. McCall probably set up his own death, then disappeared.</sup>

<sup>3. at 01:19:50 in the movie, his friend says: "*I know that a part of you died when Vivian did*" and that's also explains why she broke his heart.</sup>

<sup>FWIW: in the [original TV serie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer_(1985_TV_series)), McCall advertises for his services "*Got a problem? Odds against you? Call the Equalizer: 212 555 4200*". Sylvester Stallone is doing just that in [The_Specialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Specialist) using messages on a BBS.</sup>